# Avalanche magento theme customer login not working

Tags: magento, csrf, magento-1.8

I have installed a clean version of Avalanche (Avalanche 1.5 for Magento 1.8+), and cannot log in as a customer once I activate the package. Admin login in back end is fine.

If I register a new login, it creates the account, and logs me in. As soon as I log out, I cannot log back in again....

I can login with the default magento theme in the front end, but I cannot log in to the front end with the Avalanche theme.

I am sure I had this problem ages ago, and resolved it somehow, as I have Magento sites with the Avalanche theme working.

I have commented out the code in the Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varian.php, but this still is not resolving my problem.

I am running Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 on nginx install, but dont think that has got anything to do with it.

I am sure this has a simple fix.

I can reproduce this on a test machine on localhost, as well as on a live site.

Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION:** What a mission this was...

Find the following templates:

app/design/frontend/avalanche/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml
app/design/frontend/avalanche/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
app/design/frontend/avalanche/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/login.phtml
app/design/frontend/avalanche/default/template/checkout/onepage/login.phtml

Find code like:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form" class="site-form">
        <div class="grid_6 omega">
```

replace with:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form" class="site-form">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <div class="grid_6 omega">
```

And then you should be one step further.

Then write to the Avalance Developer, and thank him for lying that his templates are compatible with Magento 1.8+

Hope not to have to go through this again!

Comment: Any ideas, #Jake Johnson, you might have the solution for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the login form in the Avalanche theme is missing the form key.  Or the login form is being cached (block or FPC either are a problem) and the wrong form key is being served to the user.